# Issue getting context using AuthenticationManager

Tags: sharepoint-online, .net, client, office-dev-pnp

I am trying to get the context of my site using OfficeDevPnP.Core `AuthenticationManager` with the ClientID and ClientSecret

```
 var ClientId = "<>";
 var ClientSecret = "<>";

 AuthenticationManager AM = new AuthenticationManager();

 var ctx = AM.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext("https://swayams.sharepoint.com", ClientId, ClientSecret);
```

The error its throwing is -

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String, System.String)'.'

I am trying to achieve this from a .Net Core 2.0 console application.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have solved it in the meantime yourself but i ran into the same issue with PnP and an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Webservice. You have to use an Application which uses the .NET Framework and not .NET Core. As far as i know is the PnP Framework built on the standard SharePoint CSOM and there are only Assemblies for the .NET Framework.

Regards,

Johannes

Answer (score 0):

PNP only supported in full Dot Net Framework, not core.

Noticed when creating new Azure Function and default selection (V2) was blocking usage of PNP.  Fixed by creating new Project with V1 selected.

[image]